# Web hosting service too slow to run my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

I just bought 1 year of web hosting space and my page is not showing up like it should. I'm wondering if my JavaScript code is too hefty for the servers to handle, and if so, how could I find that info out?

I have a function that generates 2500 random numbers at an interval of every 200 milliseconds and adds them to the background of the page. Does that sound like something that could cause problems or should it be innocuous? It's not working when I take a look at my page. :(

Shouldn't that be a browser problem and not a server problem? I'm a tech n00b, so I don't know.

When I write the page in Notepad++ and click Run, it shows up fine. It's after I've uploaded the stuff to my CPanel and tried to view the page live that it doesn't work.

Comment: Javascript is interpreted by the browser not the server

Comment: @Philibobby [That depends on the server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_server-side_JavaScript_solutions#Server-side_JavaScript_use). But, yeah, probably *most* JavaScript is browser/client-side.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're running Node.JS (and from the sound of your question/tags, you're not), your JavaScript code will run on the client's browser, not the servers.

> I have a function that generates 2500 random numbers at an interval of every 200 milliseconds and adds them to the background of the page. Does that sound like something that could cause problems or should it be innocuous?

### Yes, very yes.

Adding things to a page (DOM manipulation) is computationally expensive.  Adding 12,500 things a second could crash the page.

Answer (score 0):

The servers do not handle any of the JavaScript, other than to throw the source code at your browser (exception: Node.JS, but I'm going to guess you're not using that)

Sounds like your host is just crap. -points shamelessly at own profile-

Comment: The quality of his hosting service is unrelated to the problem he is describing.